# Eclipselink and update trigger on multiple access to the database

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, eclipselink

in my project I have a database which many clients connect to. Concurrent access and writing works well. The problem now is not to reload the data every second from the database to always have the current status of the data.

Does Eclipselink provide a trigger mechanism on (automatically?) reload the data if the database is changed?
How would one use this trigger?

Thanks!

Comment: Copying your comment:

In a view which is a representation of a database table's content, a user can can enter some data with a separate dialog. This can be done by many users on many computers using the same database. E.g. one user has to manullay hit the "refresh" button to see the content that other users entered. I would like to automate this step, so the user doesnt have to hit the refresh button manually, but somehow I have a trigger method which is called by eclipselink so the view can be updated automatically. Hope this make my wish more clear.

– Raven 8 hours ago

Comment: It might be possible, but I don't think you can make that play nicely with JPA.  I think you'll have to flush the eclipselink caches whenever a change notification comes in.  Anyway, if you're still interested in the server-side component, then research "change notification".  There's no support for this in the SQL standards (that I know of), so each DBMS does it differently.  The only one I'm familiar with is Postgres's LISTEN and NOTIFY, which you can combine with triggers to get this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

One solution I have seen used is to use triggers in the database to send a JMS message to your application. The message is then received in a MDB where the EclipseLink cache can be invalidated or refreshed. This approach works well on an Oracle database where the trigger drops messages into an AQ table.

The are DBMS specific solutions I am familiar with but the challenge is always to get the change notification to include the table and PK values instead of a ROWID and also to ensure you are not being notified of changes you made yourself or have some way to easily filter out notices from your own changes.

I believe [GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/data-integration/059240.html) helps to address this problem but have not yet tried it myself.

Doug